# Unable to upload files with Matrix Multi-Upload

Tags: matrix

Software Versions:
EE 2.5.2
Matrix 2.5.3
Matrix Multi-Upload Accessory is version 1.1.1 but the module says version 0.9.1(downloaded today from github)

I'm able to upload fine thru Matrix, but not with Matrix Multi-Upload.

The files never fully upload with FF 19.0.2 on a Mac. They get to some random % and then show a little yield sign icon for HTTP Error and the files never make it to the server. In Safari they actually get to 100% but with the same yield icon. There are no javascript errors.

I'm using the absolute server path which starts with "/home/content/d/m/h/" so that shouldn't be the problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Howdy.  Have you checked your server error logs for any issues?  Also, does your local server path end with a trailing slash? It doesn't look like you included the full thing there.

Comment: I don't have permissions to view the server logs so I haven't checked those. It's hosted at Godaddy if there is anything special that I need to change.
Yes, the local server path does end with a slash and it works fine to upload natively thru EE and with matrix but not the multi-upload.

Comment: Is there any possibility of getting Superadmin and FTP info for some direct troubleshooting? If so, please send it to support@pixelandtonic.com and I'll be able to look at it early next week.

Comment: I can get you Superadmin access if you want to troubleshoot it. But I was in a hurry so I bought Assets and at least now I can upload multiple files at once. 
But the thumbnails don't display because I have force query strings turned on and Assets seems to add it's own ? to the URL, so the thumbnail paths don't work.
Assets thumbnails are something like this:
/index.php??ACT=48&file_id=28&size=45x67&hash=1351784545
Thumbnails display fine if I turn query strings off, but the the front-end stops working, so I need those on.

Comment: Forcing query strings should be fine. Can you try adding $config['assets_site_url'] = '/index.php';  to /system/expressionengine/config and see if that helps?  If you do need more help with Assets, I think a new post would make a lot more sense - happy to help there.  As for troubleshooting the MMU - that is entirely up to you. :) If you're not going to use it, then there may be no reason to spend time on it.

Comment: The config variable fixed the problem with Assets and forced queries. Thanks. I'm not worried about the Multi-Upload module since I have Assets now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: My pleasure! I posted the answer as a full answer, it'd be awesome if you accepted it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding:

```
$config['assets_site_url'] = '/index.php
```

to /system/expressionengine/config/config.php fixed this up.